# Twitter: quoted tweet has not a quoted_status nor a quoted_status_id

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am converting some tweet IDs into tweet object with twython (I use python 2.7 on ubuntu 14.04).

As you can see [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object), a tweet has a boolean variable `is_quote_status` with obvious (I guess) meaning. Also, there are the variables `quoted_status` and `quoted_status_id`. About these two variables you can find on the above link that "This field only surfaces when the Tweet is a quote Tweet" so i guess they should exist whenever `is_quote_status is True`.

But the first time in the dataset I find a tweet with `is_quote_status is True`, this is what I get:

```
  crazy_ID = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  twt = twitter.show_status(id = crazy_ID)
  print twt['is_quote_status']
  >>True
  print twt['quoted_status']
  >> KeyError: 'quoted_status'
  print twt['quoted_status_id']
  >> KeyError: 'quoted_status_id'
```

and I really don't know what to think about it. A direct check (i.e. `print twt`) shows me that effectively `is_quoted_status is True` but `quote_status` and `quote_status_id` are not contained in the tweet.

Let me note that the tweet was created in 2011 and I am not even sure quoted existed at that time, but if it is the case I am still wondering why `is_quoted_status is True`

So here is the question: how is that possible that a tweet has `is_quoted_status = True` but `quote_status` and `quote_status_id` are not contained in the tweet?

Comment: It depends on the Tweet ID in question, but if the parent Tweet was indeed posted in 2011, then no, quote Tweets did not exist then. If you have a Tweet from, say, 2017 that quotes a Tweet from 2011, that's perfectly possible. Unfortunately without seeing the Tweet ID in question it is impossible to help you. Does the Tweet also include a `truncated: true` value, by any chance?

Comment: I am not sure I can write the ID here. It's in a public dataset, I think I can. Do you think I can? However `truncated is false`

Comment: Hi, definitely you can paste the ID here. If the owner of the tweet has decided to protect its content, then no API endpoint would provide any content about that ID. IDs are sharable anytime anywhere. Content of the tweet is not.
Btw, I'm having the exact same problem now in 2021. Have you had any possible explanation for this case?